# How to add Hard Drive to Dell Optiplex 330 Desktop?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, dell-optiplex

I read in the [manual for the Dell Optiplex 330](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optix_330_techspecs.pdf) that I can use second HDD. Actually I want to place 2.5" SSD. But I don't even understand where can I place 3.5". Tried to remove the 1st HDD and find where I can place somewhere else but didn't find. Also, didn't find tutorials for that PC.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will fit into the 5 1/4" bay where the CD-ROM would normally go, but you'll need a drive adapter to go from 3.5" to 5 1/4"

Answer (score 2):

SSDs, since they have no moving parts, can be attached anyplace in a system where they will get adequate airflow. You can use hook-and-loop (i.e., Velcro(TM)) to fasten them whereever you can get the SATA drive and power cables to reach.

Answer (score 0):

it goes on top of hard disk 1,  i think that the screws for it are behind the front cover, you have to remove it, and there will be 4 special screws that make the second hard disk fit on the first on top, there are marks on the chassis indicating that where the disk 1 goes and where the disk 2 goes... actually i am running one optiplex 330 right now, trying to get the sata drivers for windows xp setup...